# Is Zend Framework 2.0 BETA safe for production?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I know its still in beta, but I so want to try it already and create a project and lunch it.

So a quick question, is it production safe?

Comment: BTW, I have check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883960/picking-up-zf2-is-it-worth-it-now) question, and it is outdated first, and not identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not releasing for some months, then ZF2 is very viable. Up till now, it has been okey to work with as well. [Quoting](http://framework.zend.com/zf2/blog/entry/Zend-Framework-2-0-0beta5-Released):

> This is the fifth and last in a series of planned beta releases. The
>   beta release cycle has followed the "gmail" style of betas, whereby
>   new features have been added in each new release, and backwards
>   compatibility (BC) has not been guaranteed. The desire has been for
>   developers to adopt and work with new components as they are shipped,
>   and provide feedback so we can polish the distribution.

so for each release, we have had to modify some small stuff. But this is almost just "setup-code" and no big changes to our controllers or view scripts.

And now this will be even better:

> At this time, we anticipate few if any BC breaks between now and the
>   first release candidate (RC). Applications built today on beta5 will
>   operate in the way we expect them to for the stable release.

so grab ZF2 now if you will need to learn it anyway some day. If you're only building one single application and need to ship it fast, I think ZF1 would be a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I would avoid using a framework that is still in beta for a production project.

As quoted from the Zend website [here](http://devzone.zend.com/1935/zend-framework-200beta1-released/):

> Once all code in the proposed standard distribution
>   has reached maturity and reasonable stability, we will freeze the API and
>   prepare for Release Candidate status.

So basically, aside from likely encountering bugs you can expect API's to change right until they have reached the Release Candidate milestone (whenever that may be).

Comment: Yeah, changes in API's can be very problematic indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was correct in the moment I asked, but not at the moment. But for the effort +1 from me. :)

Comment: @Jaitsu, Correct, but the problem with the api is almost gone, and but, if the check the quoted link in the accepted answer, `Applications built today on beta5 will operate in the way we expect them to for the stable release.` So its safe build application using zf2 from now on.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. When are you deploying to customers? Beta 5 was just released and the next few releases will be Release Candidates. That means no more major changes. So your ZF code can remain pretty stable.

ZF2 release date remains by the end of Summer. If you aren't deploying to customers before then, I'd strongly consider v2. We did and have been using ZF2 since beta 3. We preferred to pick the latest technology rather than be stuck with v1 for 10 years (the minimum expected lifespan of our application; we're B2B).